# How can I compile code that uses getsubopt()?

Tags: c, parsing, command-line-arguments, getopt

I want to parse a list of options of the form `key1=val1, key2=val2, etc` (like the options to `mount -o`).  The `getsubopt()` function seems perfect for this task (http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Suboptions.html).  However, when I try to compile my code using gcc, I get:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getsubopt’
```

and the program segfaults when I run it.

I added `#include <stdlib.h>` but the compiler doesn't pick up the declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <stdlib.h>
```

at the top of the file that contains the call to `getsubopt`? The error you are getting is what you would expect if you call a function which has not been declared.

Comment: Note that `_XOPEN_SOURCE` set to `700` is loosely equivalent to `_POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L`,
`_XOPEN_SOURCE` set to `600` is loosely equivalent to `_POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L`,
and `_XOPEN_SOURCE` set to `500` is loosely equivalent to `_POSIX_C_SOURCE 199506L`.  You may prefer to use 700 rather than 500.